# hasOneThrough Laravel Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tabes categories, sub_categories & products

- category table

```
---------------------
| id | category_name |
---------------------
```

- sub_category table

```
--------------------------------------------
| id | category_id(FK) | sub_category_name |
--------------------------------------------
```

- product table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| id | sub_category_id(FK) | product_name | product_description |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**How do I get product category name using hasOneThrough eloquent relationship ( or using any other relationship).
I tried this in product model **

```
public function category(){
return $this->hasOneThrough(
    Category::class, 
    SubCategory::class
);
```

}

**But it gives error: Unknown column 'sub_categories.product_id'**

Comment: You can use one table for category and subcategory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install this external package [staudenmeir/belongs-to-through](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through) to add the relationship you need.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function subCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToThrough(Category::class, SubCategory::class);
    }
}

class SubCategory extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, SubCategory::class);
    }
}
```

If you need to access Category directly from Product, and want to use laravels functions like `$product->category()->attach($category->id)` etc, then you need this dependency to achieve that.

If you are ok with doing:

```
    $product->subCategory->category;
    // or
    $product->subCategory->category()->attach($category->id);
```

Then you don't need the dependency and you can exclude the category relationship on the Product model.

Comment: So is there any other way without using any external package?

Comment: you missed out one line-  use \Znck\Eloquent\Traits\BelongsToThrough;

Comment: Wasn't meant to be a complete implementation, but a solution :). Otherwise I missed <?php, namespace, different filenames etc.